# Chrome Performance showing a lot of "other" processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome

[image: a lot of "other"]

I am having performance issues on chrome. I am running a large single page application with a lot of script, but the code is fairly well organized and I am killing un-needed processes. I don't know how to find where all this "other" processing is coming from.

If you know how to investigate further. or give me a key word to google besides "other" that would be much appreciated.

I am using a lot of panZoom https://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/. but I am calling destroy() on every instance that is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

So for panZoom you will need to call reset() before destroy(). because that's how it works I didn't write it. and as I was starting up and shutting down more and more panZoom instances I had the js equivalent of a memory leak and I am ASUMING that's what all the a "other" processing was.